# MouseDown on Picturebox error: Handles clause requires a WithEvents

Tags: vb.net, handler, picturebox, mousedown

I am brand new to VB- in the following code I get this error.

Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types. (BC30506)

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown
```

Basically I am trying to move a picture box object with mousedown event as per this snippet

```
  Private Offset As Size 'used to hold the distance of the mouse`s X and Y position to the picturebox Left and Top postition

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown
    Dim ptc As Point = Me.PointToClient(MousePosition) 'get the mouse position in client coordinates
    Offset.Width = ptc.X - PictureBox1.Left 'get the width distance of the mouse X position to the picturebox`s Left position
    Offset.Height = ptc.Y - PictureBox1.Top 'get the height distance of the mouse Y position to the picturebox`s Top position
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then 'make sure the left mouse button is down first
        Dim ptc As Point = Me.PointToClient(MousePosition) 'get the mouse position in client coordinates
        PictureBox1.Left = ptc.X - Offset.Width 'set the Left position of picturebox to the mouse position - the offset width distance
        PictureBox1.Top = ptc.Y - Offset.Height 'set the Top position of picturebox to the mouse position - the offset height distance
    End If
End Sub
```

I have read the other questions and can't seem to grasp exactly why this code is not working.

Comment: You created the PictureBox in code, didnt you?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use your code you need to declare `PictureBox1` as `Friend WithEvents` like every control created by designer:

```
Friend WithEvents PictureBox1
```

But you can use [`Friend`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/08w05ey2.aspx) only at the module, interface, or namespace level. Therefore, the declaration context for a `Friend` element must be a source file, a namespace, an interface, a module, a class, or a structure; it can't be a procedure.

If you can't created your controls at runtime with this declaration you have to use [`AddHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx) to associates an event with an event handler.

For example:

```
AddHandler Me.PictureBox1.MouseDown, AddressOf PictureBox1_MouseDown
AddHandler Me.PictureBox1.MouseMove, AddressOf PictureBox1_MouseMove
```

You also have to remove `Handles` from procedure declaration; i.e.:

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    'your code here
End Sub
```

TIP: if you want you could use a better name for your event handler instead of the default name; i.e.:

```
AddHandler Me.PictureBox1.MouseMove, AddressOf movePictureBoxOnMouseLeftClick

Private Sub movePictureBoxOnMouseLeftClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    'your code here
End Sub
```

Comment: Okay I got this to work-  BUT I am not grasping this conceptually at all.

Comment: added some explanation and link to msdn.